# Fixed DIV Positioning Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have been working on my reporting template and not able to figure out position of the details contains (right hand side):  http://relevantcodes.com/Tools/ExtentReports2/ExtentJava210.html

I am having an issue with scrolling which I am not able to figure out.  Please see the 2 images below:

Before scroll:

[image]

After scroll:

[image]

In the 2nd image, notice the extra space at the top when the scroll happens on the left size (where all tests are stored).  It happens as the DIV is fixed but I wanted to know if there is a way to position it to the top when we scroll down?

Another issue is that when we open the menu (by clicking the bars in the corner-top-left), the left-container overlaps the right-container.  How can I fix this issue?  Is setting a new width for the right-container using js a good approach?

[image]

Would love to hear your suggestions and hopefully find an elegant solution to this issue which I am not able to figure out..

Comment: do you want the right div fixed ? i mean it be should displayed  always ?

Comment: and you said what is the issue, but i guess you forgot to mention what you are expecting

Comment: Santhosh: yes, I would like the right side container div to remain fixed.  Left side contain the tests which users should be able to scroll because there can be 100s of them.  The right side has details and only one test details will be viewed at once so it should remain fixed as the user scrolls the left section.  Hope that clarifies.

Comment: simple solution is make navbar fixed, then only left div will scrolled and you will not get any space on top of right div. if you don't want navbar to be fixed , then give me some time to fix @Anshoo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue 1

1.Remove `.pinned {    position: fixed !important;}` at line 6 in file(materialize.min.css).
2.Use below JS

```
$('.vh100').css('position', 'absolute')// to add aboslute position by default.
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(window).scrollTop() > 48) // nav bar height is 48 px
  {
    $('.vh100').css('position', 'fixed'); // add position fixed if scrolling is done and scroll top is greater than 48 px which is the nav bar
    $('.vh100').css('margin-top', '-48px'); // when scroll up you have assign negative margin-top so that the space will not be appeared.
  } else {
    $('.vh100').removeAttr('style'); // remove margin-top
    $('.vh100').css('position', 'absolute'); // and add position absolute
  }
});
```

Issue 2(ExternalJava210.html --> Line :3273)

add and remove position of `.vh100` when `.menu-toggle` is clicked.

Comment: J Santosh - thanks for this, I was able to utilize your code (with a few modifications) and solve both issues.  Also fixed the menu-toggle expand issue by dynamically setting the width of the container.  Cheers!

Comment: Santosh - just checked that using this technique, the image lightbox does not work correctly.  In the test "Uses Media", if we click any image, the image does not show completely.  Will try to figure this one out.  Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

For your first problem, I believe the only way you'd be able to acomplish that is by a javascript listener - listening for when the user scrolls and changing the position from `position:absolute/relative` to `position:fixed` after they scroll down `Ypx`. 
*Disclaimer : there could be a css way of doing it i am not aware of.*

For your second problem with the overlapping, I would set the div that slides out to `position:absolute` so that instead of moving the whole page (and taking resources redrawing all the elements) it just glides over the rest of your content. Maybe put a background behind it that fades out the content behind it.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Your second problem goes away if you remove the `fixed` position on that second column, everything rearranges nicely without that. I would say that the best approach is to remove that `.pinned` rule from your CSS and handle the position of the column with JS.

Get the height of your nav and the dashboard (regardless of it being visible or not), then compare that resulting height to your scroll position. With that you should be able to place that column precisely where you want it.